# Font Awesome Light via CSS

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome

I have the pro version of [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/), which gives me access to light-styled icons. I am creating icons (e.g.: [address book icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/address-card)) via CSS like so:

```
.icon-link::before { content: "\f2bb" }
```

However, this only renders the normal version of the icon, not the light version. What can I do to render the light version of an icon, entirely using CSS (or even Javascript/JQuery) but **not HTML**?

I am **not** interested in the common solution of digging into the HTML and adding the `.fal` (font awesome light) class to each applicable object or a parent or whatever.

Comment: Have you imported the proper CSS file into your HTML? Also, I think there are supposed to be 2 colons when using the before key word unless you're using IE8. ".icon-link::before". You also may need "font-family: FontAwesome;" in your CSS before the content.

Comment: Hi Paul. You're right about the colons. I'll make the correction. What is the proper file to put into my HTML? And how would just putting "font-family: FontAwesome;" into the CSS make the text light, without selecting light? Maybe I want some of my icons to be light and others to be normal or bold.

Comment: Use "<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourCSSFileLocationOrURL.css">" in the head of your HTML. When you bought the icons, did they give you a CSS file to download or a link you could reference?

Comment: Yeah. I have attached the stylesheet they provided. The problem is that I cannot get the icons to display in "light" mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. You've got to add: `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro"` and `font-weight: 100` (or whatever font-weight you want).

Comment: Well to answer your other question, that's why you need to add the font-family, lol.

Comment: I am trying to reduce the thickness of the plus size here. I tried adding fontFamily and fontWeight but it didn't seem to work. Could you look at this? https://snack.expo.io/@lindapaiste/022490

Comment: this answer is partially wrong and misleading. the weight of the font in FontAwesome is done by font-style regular, light or solid, not the font-weight argument